APA Figure Formatting and Numbering in Quarto PDF Output
I’m working on a project in Quarto, and I’m having trouble getting my figure numbering and captions to behave correctly according to APA standards. I need a setup where the figures follow these requirements:
Figure captions and subcaptions must adhere to APA style (caption on top of the figure).
Notes should be placed directly underneath the figure.
I need to disable automatic numbering for specific figures, while still maintaining APA-compliant captions and notes.
This setup is required for generating a PDF output, with all formatting adhering to the APA standards.
Here’s an example of the code I’m using:
---
fig-cap-location: top
fig-numbers: false
format:
    pdf:
        fig-numbering: false
        fontsize: 12pt
        linestretch: 1.5
        geometry: "left=25mm, right=20mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm"
        classoption: oneside
        papersize: a4
        header-includes:
           - \usepackage{float}
           - \floatplacement{table}{H}
           - \usepackage{tikz}
           - \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, calc}
           - \usepackage{geometry}
           - \geometry{margin=1in}
           - \usepackage{caption}
           - \DeclareCaptionFormat{APAfigure}{\textbf{#1#2}\\[1.5\baselineskip]\textit{#3}}
           - \captionsetup[figure]{format=APAfigure, labelsep=none, justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=false, font=small}
          
fontsize: 12pt
engine: knitr
bibliography: ../bibliography.bib
csl: ../apa.csl
---


```{r, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, echo = FALSE)
```



:::{#fig-study1-models}

```{r fig-study1-models}
#| fig-numbering: false
#| fig-subcap:
#|   - "Model 1.1"
#|   - "Model 1.2"
#|   - "Model 1.3"
#|   - "Model 1.4"
#| layout: "[[1,1], [1.2,0.9]]"
#| out.width: "90%"

knitr::include_graphics(c("figures/model1_1.tex", 
                          "figures/model1_2.tex", 
                          "figures/model1_3.tex", 
                          "figures/model1_4.tex"))
```

\raggedright \textit{Note.} Here the note that appears underneath the figure"

This is the caption underneath the figure number
:::



::: {#fig-study2-models}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}

```{r fig-study2-models}
#| number: false
#| fig-subcap:
#|   - "Model 2.1"
#|   - "Model 2.2"
#| layout: "[[1,1]]"
#| out.width: "100%"

knitr::include_graphics(c("figures/model2_1.tex", 
                          "figures/model2_2.tex"))
```


\raggedright \textit{Note.} Figure Note.

Figure Caption
:::

I’ve tried using fig-numbering: false and adding custom LaTeX commands, but it seems that either the numbering or the placement of the note doesn't come out correctly.
Thanks in advance for your help!
When just relying on formatting the Caption and Note in the r chunks, I can't get the Note to be displayed at all or not underneath the figure.
Any help on getting this to work properly while adhering to APA formatting would be much appreciated!

solved this by:
:::{fig-study1-models}
```{r fig-study1-models}
#| fig-cap: "Caption Above The Figure"
#| fig-subcap:
#|   - "Model 1.1"
#|   - "Model 1.2"
#|   - "Model 1.3"
#|   - "Model 1.4"
#| layout: "[[1,1], [1.2,0.9]]"
#| out.width: "90%"

knitr::include_graphics(c("figures/model1_1.tex", 
                          "figures/model1_2.tex", 
                          "figures/model1_3.tex", 
                          "figures/model1_4.tex"))
```

::: {fig-note}
\raggedright \textit{Note.} Figure Note underneath the figure"
:::
:::

::: {fig-study2-models}
```{r fig-study2-models}
#| fig-cap: "Figure Caption above"
#| fig-subcap:
#|   - "Model 2.1"
#|   - "Model 2.2"
#| layout: "[[1,1]]"
#| out.width: "100%"

knitr::include_graphics(c("figures/model2_1.tex", 
                          "figures/model2_2.tex"))
```

::: {fig-note} 
\raggedright \textit{Note.} Figure note...
:::
:::

